# Find Element with Text, then Select Element Many Levels Above it

Tags: html, dom, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that deletes a section of a website. To do this, I need to find a `<span>` that contains some text, and then select the containing `<div>` tag. Often this tag will be many levels above the span in the DOM, and it doesn't have a consistent attribute to select by.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div> <!-- I want to select this DIV -->
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>some text</span>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have used `//span[text() = 'some text'` to find the right `<span>` but now I need to go back up to the first `<div>` in the example HTML

Have tried `//*[ancestor::span[text() = 'some text']]` and `//span[ancestor::*[text() = 'some text']]`. Yes these would only go up to the first parent, but that's not even working for me, even though they come up as valid XPath expressions when I test on [XPath Tester](https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html).

What is the simplest way of writing an XPath expression that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution I have found is to use `ancestor` in the XPath query, because I am often wanting to traverse up many levels.

Examples

```
//span[text() = 'some text']/ancestor::*[4]
```

selects the fourth element up from the selected span, regardless of what type those elements might be.

```
//span[text() = 'some text']/ancestor::a[2]
```

Will find the second anchor tag up from the selected span, provided it is a direct ascendant of the span.

Answer (score 1):

You might try with the `../` syntax to go up one level (ie: to the immediate parent ) and chain them like so:

```js
const getnodes=function( expr, parent ){
        let results=[];
        let contextNode=parent || document;
        let query=document.evaluate( expr, contextNode, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
        for ( let i=0, length=query.snapshotLength; i < length; ++i ) {
            results.push( query.snapshotItem( i ) );
        }
        return results;
    };
  
  let col=getnodes( '//span[ text()="some text" ]/../../../../../div', document.body );
  col.forEach( n=>console.info( n.textContent ) )
```

```html
<!--This is the div I want to select -->
  <div>top
    <div>a
        <div>b
            <div>c
                <span>some text</span>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```